# How to get other Sub-Elements of an XML element whose one of the sub element is known?

Tags: xpath

This is an xpath question, 
I xml file that looks likes this there are several of these artists in the xml.

```
  <lib>
   <artist>
         <name>Katy Perry</name>
         <album>
           <name>The Official Uk Top 40 Singles Chart 27-05-2012</name>
           <file>
             <name>37 Katy Perry - Part Of Me.mp3</name>
           </file>
        </album>
        <album>
           <name>Album name 2</name>
           <file>
             <name>whatever.mp3</name>
           </file>
        </album>
   </artist>
   ...
 </lib>
```

How can I get all the albums of the artist given an artist name using an XPath ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be like this:

```
/lib/artist[name = 'Katy Perry']/album
```

Does that work for what you're trying to do?

To account for leading or trailing space, or unexpected space between the words, you should be able to do the following:

```
/lib/artist[normalize-space(name) = 'Katy Perry']/album
```

Comment: I thought we could use square brackets for attributes ?? I could be wrong, I will try it out..

Comment: No, the square brackets (also known as a predicate) are used for filtering the expression. Attributes are indicated with `@`.

Comment: thanks, it worked as I expected except if there is newline character in the name element or leading/trailing space then it does not work.. I can modify the xml generation any advise  on that ?

Comment: Please try the modified formula above.  I believe that should account for the whitespace issues.